# Unable to request API server properly

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests, request

I am trying to get an API GET request through, but I've run in to the following error.

```
curl --location "https://openapi.planday.com/hr/v1/employees" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "X-ClientId: <ID>" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>"
```

Which results in:

> Jwt is not in the form of Header.Payload.Signature with two dots and 3 sections

This is the documentation on the official website of Planday API: https://openapi.planday.com/gettingstarted/authorization

I've tried with some `curl -X GET` and `--request GET` commands, which gives me a curl error of "illegal or incorrect URL formatting", and sometimes it just says i have not specified the ID (which is specified from the X-ClientID earlier or later in the command).

I am expecting to get a Json file as result of either Schedule or HR (depending on the site im testing).

Furthermore I've tried via Python code:

```
response = requests.get('https://openapi.planday.com/scheduling/v1.0/shifts',
  headers= {"Authorization":"Bearer <TOKEN>", 'X-ClientId':'<ID>'})
```

Which gives the response of 401. I am hoping in the end to get this integrated in a Python script, so if you have a lead on the python side of it, i would really appreciate it:)

I'm new to web communication, so sorry if it is a bit nooby question (and please dont be too harsh lol)
Thanks for any help in advance:))

Comment: It's important to make sure the code and error messages presented in your question are *readable*. Take a minute to read the help available in the editor to learn how to properly format things. I've fixed things up a bit just now, but in the future you want to make it as easy as possible for people to understand your question.

Comment: The error in response to your initial `curl` command seems to suggest that the value of `<TOKEN>` is incorrect. It's likely that your `requests.get` call is returning the same error (you can inspect `response.text`).